# How to keep AngularJS factories DRY

Tags: angularjs, dry, angularjs-factory

In my AngularJS app, I have a lot of different factories for making different `REST` requests.

Going over them, I realized that all of them use a lot of similar code. This is terrible for DRYness and also makes this messy and longer then necessary.

For example, they all do the same checks for `cache`s:

```
        // Cache stuff
        var cacheName = 'projects.rsrc.getProjectUsersService';
        var cache = cacheAppFactory.get(cacheName);
        if(clearCache) {
            cacheAppFactory.clear(cacheName);
        }
```

I want to simply place this code in ONE function which takes a `cacheName` and call it from every factory.

Is there a way to reference some "global" code, or functions, from inside factories?

Comment: You can look at service inheritence http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/

Comment: Remember factory can take a dependency on another factory, so the code can be packaged into a factory\service itself

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the functionality of your cache factory to register every other factory that uses the cache functionality of the cache factory.

Then simply create a method in the cache factory that would return caches from all the registered factories.

That's probably as DRY as you can get and the similar principle can be applied to all the things you think are repeating too much, not just the cache stuff.